# Dovecot works with mail.example.com but not with example.com (they represent the same IP)

Tags: dovecot

Assume I have a VPS, with the domain name `example.com.`. I run a mail server using `postfix` and `dovecot`.

I configured `dovecot` to retrieve my mail using `IMAP`. With my mail client, it works if I use the mail server `mail.example.com.`, but it doesn't if I use `example.com.`.

However, I would like to use `example.com.` as a mail server. Indeed, the trusted certificate I have only works for `example.com.` and `www.example.com.`.

I can't find in all the configuration files how I can change this.

Comment: It would help if you post the mail client error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dovecot does not know the name you use to connect to your server. You configure your mail client (usually called MUA for mail user agent) with your username, password, protocol, and server name. The MUA obtains the IP of the server, connects to that IP using the protocol, and offers the username and password. As long as you are not using SSL, the server name has no importance as long as the IP is the same.

If using mail.example.com as server name works, and using example.com as server name does not work, then there are two possibilities:

1. The names mail.example.com and example.com do not have the same IP. Test this with the `host`, `dig`, or `ping` commands. It is quite possible that example.com does not have an IP at all. Many (most?) browsers will happily add on a `www.` if `http://example.com` does not return an IP.
2. There is an SSL certificate problem. Dovecot may have installed a snakeoil certificate for mail.example.com which doesn't work for example.com.

The error you get when using example.com should be the first thing you look at, but I realize that some MUAs are sadly lacking in useful error messages. To test manually from a unix machine, assuming that you are using SSL:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:993
openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:993
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! Don't hesitate to tell us what the problem actually was :)